# Google Sheet for arrayformula

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to write a Google Sheet that has three columns, A,B, &C.  This is to calculate the cash in a till and a float of $200.  In column A is the list of denominations from $100 down to .05, in column B the employee puts the number of each currency in the till and totals the amount in a new cell and in the cell below that it shows how much to take out to leave exactly $200 left in the till.  What I am trying to do is in column C beside each denomination show how many of each to take out to leave the $200 in the till.  In column C I have the following
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B18 < 0, IF(A2:A16 > 0, MIN(QUOTIENT(B18, A2:A16), B2:B16), 0), 0))
but all I get is 0's all down, what is wrong with this code?

here is my code from column c

=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B18 < 0, IF(A2:A16 > 0, MIN(QUOTIENT(B18, A2:A16), B2:B16), 0), 0))

Comment: The purpose of each cell and range in your formula is not clear. Please provide a worked example including an example of the successful outcome of your formula.

Answer (score 1):

The `min()` function is an aggregating function that returns just one value, even in an `arrayformula()` context.

To evaluate `min()` over a range of values, use a [lambda](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718) helper function such as `map()` or `byrow()`, like this:

```
=map(A2:A16, B2:B16, lambda(a, b, 
  ifs( 
    B18 >= 0, 0, 
    a > 0, min(B18 / a, b), 
    true, b 
  ) 
))
```

See [map()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12568985) and [byrow()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12570930).